# SOLR JDBC failing with Could not initialize class org.apache.solr.handler.sql.SolrRules at org.apache.solr.handler.sql.SolrTableScan.register

Tags: solr, solrj

When trying to run a SOLR query,

> SELECT count(*) from products;

we are seeing the below exception from solr server, ours is a SOLR cloud setup,
SOLR version - solr-8.8.2-PATCH2
solr-solrj-8.8.2 version

Complete Stack Trace i have mentioned below,

```
2023-02-09 14:21:34.824 ERROR (qtp1209411469-15) [c:products s:shard3 r:core_node12 x:otmm_shard3_replica_n10] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.solr.handler.sql.SolrRules
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.sendError(HttpSolrCall.java:746)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:592)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.solr.handler.sql.SolrRules
    at org.apache.solr.handler.sql.SolrTableScan.register(SolrTableScan.java:72)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.AbstractRelOptPlanner.onNewClass(AbstractRelOptPlanner.java:239)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.onNewClass(VolcanoPlanner.java:464)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.AbstractRelOptPlanner.registerClass(AbstractRelOptPlanner.java:230)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.registerImpl(VolcanoPlanner.java:1224)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.register(VolcanoPlanner.java:589)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.ensureRegistered(VolcanoPlanner.java:604)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.ensureRegistered(VolcanoPlanner.java:84)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.AbstractRelNode.onRegister(AbstractRelNode.java:268)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.registerImpl(VolcanoPlanner.java:1132)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.register(VolcanoPlanner.java:589)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.ensureRegistered(VolcanoPlanner.java:604)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.ensureRegistered(VolcanoPlanner.java:84)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.AbstractRelNode.onRegister(AbstractRelNode.java:268)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.registerImpl(VolcanoPlanner.java:1132)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.setRoot(VolcanoPlanner.java:265)
    at org.apache.calcite.tools.Programs.lambda$standard$3(Programs.java:262)
    at org.apache.calcite.tools.Programs$SequenceProgram.run(Programs.java:331)
    at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.optimize(Prepare.java:166)
    at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:297)
    at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:208)
    at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare2_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:642)
    at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:508)
    at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepareSql(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:478)
    at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.parseQuery(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:231)
    at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteMetaImpl.prepareAndExecute(CalciteMetaImpl.java:556)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareAndExecuteInternal(AvaticaConnection.java:675)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:156)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeQuery(AvaticaStatement.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.JDBCStream.open(JDBCStream.java:278)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.ExceptionStream.open(ExceptionStream.java:52)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.StreamHandler$TimerStream.open(StreamHandler.java:465)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.TupleStream.writeMap(TupleStream.java:82)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JsonTextWriter.writeMap(JsonTextWriter.java:164)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.TextWriter.writeMap(TextWriter.java:216)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.TextWriter.writeVal(TextWriter.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:153)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JsonTextWriter.writeNamedListAsMapWithDups(JsonTextWriter.java:387)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JsonTextWriter.writeNamedList(JsonTextWriter.java:293)
    at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeResponse(JSONWriter.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.response.JSONResponseWriter.write(JSONResponseWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.solr.response.QueryResponseWriterUtil.writeQueryResponse(QueryResponseWriterUtil.java:65)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.writeResponse(HttpSolrCall.java:890)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:583)
    ... 40 more
```

The same happens from DB GUI as well, i referred below link

https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/jdbc-dbvisualizer.html

I have added below jars(WHich i took from SOLR server)
[image]

From DB GUI as well same issue happens. I added ,
solr-solrj-8.8.2.jar
and other dependency jars

Kindly let me know what is being wrong with this.
Iam using Solrj, and i have a application it supports only JDBC and iam in a situation to use only JDBC solr using SOLRJ,
Its basically a BIRT reporting tool.
Where we can define SQL and output would be automatically mapped to the report.

This is what we are trying to do

Added below in solr.in.sh
SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.modules=sql"
And in solr admin, can able to see,

Args in Systemdashboard,
-Dsolr.modules=sql

Comment: -PATCH2 is not an official release. SQL is not the "standard" way of querying Solr either, and so it would be helpful to know A) what has been patched, and B) exactly what feature of solr you are presenting this SQL query to. Also it appears you likely have a stack trace but you haven't shared anything but the message from it. Please share the whole stack trace.

Comment: Also i have enabled the below Module,
https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/sql-query.html
In solr.sh file i have added
SOLR_MODULES=sql

Comment: So it looks like we've solved the initial problem, and your response that you pasted says it is a successful request (status:0). This message `"_useParamsExpanded_":{"_EXPORT":"[NOT AVAILABLE]"},` looks like you are trying to use a param set that was configured on your other server, but is not configured on this one, which is probably why you are not getting the results you expect. If you need help troubleshooting that issue, you should probably start a new question so that people with a similar problem can find it and be helped by it too.

Comment: My local solr response same _useParamsExpanded_":{"_EXPORT":"[NOT AVAILABLE]"} and its working fine, Gus actually this is the state from start, can you kindly provide some insight on why the query still says, class not available?

Comment: I don't understand? Where do you see 'class not available' in the response (I assume you mean response not query)

Comment: Yes when I execute the query am getting no class found solr table, we tried enabling solr modules and it loaded as well, but still we are getting no classdef found solrrules. Since am getting tat exception we were not able to see the resultset. We need to fix the error I assume for getting the result set

Comment: So you are seeing the exception in the logs every time you submit the sql query? Even when you get the (success) result you posted? (`"status":0` says it's claiming to be a successful response even though it isn't the results you expect).  I understand that english may not be your best language, but the lack of precision in your terminology has been creating confusion, please note that the query is what you send, the response is what you get back and the logs are well.. the logs :) )

Comment: Let's try this: add exactly the code that you use to issue the query (either solrj code, or the request URL & any post data), Then show exactly the response you get back from the server. Then please ensure that the stack trace is specifically from that exact request. Also, if it's not working via SolrJ try the same query via /solr/<collection>/sql as shown here: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/parallel-sql-interface.html#http-interface and include any information about how that differs (if at all) from the solrj query.

Comment: Also delete from the question anything that is redundant out of date or in conflict with what you get while following this suggestion.

Comment: Also it's just occurred to me that the JSON you posted looks like a result from the config api, more than a result from a query, but I have no idea why you would be adding information about the export handler? When I query the config api on mine I get a LOT more information than that (though as I said, 9.1 is what I have running locally at the moment).

Comment: And just be clear when I say the exact code I mean the exact code of your MRE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example) not your application code.

Comment: Hi @Gus, the status 0 is just for the export API, the below one is giving,
http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/config/requestHandler?componentName=/export&expandParams=true

So my query is just, select count(*) from collection_name;
This works fine in /solr/<collection>/sql 

But from GUI or SolrJ, am getting the exception I mentioned below,
Could not initialize class org.apache.solr.handler.sql.SolrRules

One more clarity is, the query works fine in my local and not in our server

Comment: Hi @Gus, kindly let me know if any more info is required

Comment: (second time) Let's try this: add exactly the code that you use to issue the query (either solrj code, or the request URL & any post data), Then show exactly the response you get back from the server. Then please ensure that the stack trace is specifically from that exact request. And just be clear when I say the exact code I mean the exact code of your MRE (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example) not your application code.

Comment: @Gus Thank you so much for the support so far, also  the Query is in question, i was issuing a simple select count statement from DB GUI. Just a select statement from DB GUI. Am using this DB GUI - https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/jdbc-dbvisualizer.html

Comment: Ok so this is very relevant to the question and it would be best if your question had a screen shot of how you configured the GUI (similar to what is in the ref guide, but your actual settings). In stack overflow we like to have all the information in the question, readers should not need to read this loooong series of comments to find the critical information (in case they later have a better answer than I). Also please remove the out put for /export config or explain why you think it is relevant (in the question). If DbVisualizer shows what libraries you have loaded please show that too.

Comment: Also, cleaning up the question is important so that future folks with questions can understand if your question is similar to theirs.

Comment: @Gus Modified the question and added the necessary configs i did in DB GUI

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I just realized you had linked to the wrong docs for your version. The way you are trying to add modules was not available until 9.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-15914) 8.8 docs are at: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/ Note that until recently this feature was called Parallel Sql https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/parallel-sql-interface.html**

For 8.8 you shouldn't need to configure modules since at that time /sql was an implicitly loaded request handler.

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/implicit-requesthandlers.html

You may need to verify if the implicit handlers have been (mis)configured via the request parameters API (https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/implicit-requesthandlers.html#how-to-edit-implicit-handler-paramsets)

---

Below refers to the 9.x versions of solr

---

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.solr.handler.sql.SolrRules
```

Probably indicates that you have not successfully loaded the sql module. Normally one enables modules at the very bottom of `solr.in.sh` not `solr.sh` as you said in your comments. `solr.in.sh` is the place where Solr intends for you to set up environment variables. One really shouldn't ever need to modify `solr.sh` directly, and doing so may make upgrades difficult in the future.

Check that there isn't another set of enablements in `solr.in.sh` that is overwriting what you've tried to do in `solr.sh`. Also check that you aren't enabling any other modules in other ways (several methods are shown here: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/solr-modules.html). You should pick one way of enabling modules (sysprops, solr.in.sh, solr.xml or solrconfig.xml) and then enable all modules that way to avoid having to understand any complicated precedence logic if possible. I don't know the precedence order, but I can probably figure it out if you have other modules and absolutely can't avoid using more than one method.

Also, you still haven't told us where you got the version ending in -PATCH2. This version spec sounds like you are working with some folks who are compiling their own custom Solr, so you should be sure to understand what they've changed in case they've customized something about how or where Solr loads jar files (not very likely, but one never knows).

Comment: Thanks for throwing some lights. Also i have version of SOLR installed in my local - 8.11.2, which works fine with sql, in our other environemnt, i have 8.8.2, where it is not working, Also i tried, adding SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.modules=sql" in solr.in.sh, and still not working, restarted the service as well. i will add screenshot in my posts

Comment: The below is response,
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2},
  "config":{"requestHandler":{"/export":{
        "class":"solr.ExportHandler",
        "useParams":"_EXPORT",
        "components":["query"],
        "invariants":{
          "rq":"{!xport}",
          "distrib":false},
        "name":"/export",
        "_useParamsExpanded_":{"_EXPORT":"[NOT AVAILABLE]"},
        "_effectiveParams_":{
          "distrib":"false",
          "rq":"{!xport}"}}}}}

Comment: Also yes, we are using a wrapper on top of SOLR and so only PATCH.